# How can I create a Stream<String[]> with only one element with Stream.of?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, variadic-functions, type-inference

Using `Stream.of` to create generic streams is very convenient, but what if I want to create a `Stream<String[]>` of only one element?

Let’s say I have:

```
String[] tropicalFruits = new String[] {"pineapple", "banana", "mango"};
String[] fruits = new String[] {"melon", "peach", "apple"};
```

Then `Stream.of(tropicalFruits, fruits)` produces a `Stream<String[]>` of two elements. How can I achieve the same for a stream of a single element? If I try:

```
Stream<String[]> fruityStream = Stream.of(tropicalFruits);
```

I get:

> Error: incompatible types: inference variable `T` has incompatible
>   bounds
>   equality constraints: `java.lang.String[]`
>   lower bounds: `java.lang.String`
>
> ```
> Stream<String[]> fruityStream = Stream.of(fruits);
>                                  ^---------------^
> ```

I’ve googled for this and searched in SO but I got nothing. It seems to me that it’s not a very unusual or esoeteric problem, so it’s kind of surprising I didn’t get any answers (or I’m not searching with the right keywords).

Comment: You can use Stream.Builder<T>

Comment: Right answer for a different question. :)

Comment: Why different? `Stream<String[]> stream = Stream.<String[]>builder().add(new String[] {"a", "b"}).build();` is also correct solution, even though it's not as simple as **accepted** answer. @Alf

Comment: Your solution doesn’t use `Stream.of`, which was the whole point.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Solution

```
Stream<String[]> stream = Stream.<String[]>of(tropicalFruits);
```

or

```
Stream<String[]> stream = Stream.of(new String[][]{tropicalFruits});
```

### Explanation

To produce a [`Stream<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), `Stream.of` takes either [`T`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T-) or [`T...`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-).
A `T[]` parameter perfectly applies to the second signature.
Therefore, passing a `String[]` invokes the `Stream.of(String...)` version.

To change this behaviour, we need to provide some extra information about `T` (1) or define it more clearly (=unambiguously) (2).

There are two ideas came to my mind:

1. To specify a type argument of the method explicitly to use the first signature.
   `Stream.<String[]>of(new String[]{})` will produce a `Stream<String[]>`.
2. To wrap a `T[]` value in a `T[][]` array to use the second signature.
   `Stream.of(new String[][]{})` will produce a `Stream<String[]>`.

Comment: oh shoot the more type information adding is awesome! you should explain the first one I guess :)

Comment: Better answer than mine!  The first one looks like it takes advantage of varargs, which is awesome.

Comment: I like the other two answers by Jacob and Eugene but I think the second solution is the most correct one since it doesn’t need the creation of any additional arrays or lists.

Comment: In the [`List.of(E...)` method's javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-), this case is covered by an API Note: *This method also accepts a single array as an argument. The element type of the resulting list will be the component type of the array, and the size of the list will be equal to the length of the array. To create a list with a single element that is an array, do the following:* `String[] array = ... ; List<String[]> list = List.<String[]>of(array);`. I think this API note should be added to the `Stream.of(E...)` method's docs as well.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner that's very interesting, *usually* adding more type information works in the sense that the target is inferred this way; but here it is actually for choosing an overloaded method. excellent comment!

Answer (score 6):

This `Stream<String[]> fruittyStream = Stream.of(tropicalFruits);`

calls the var-arg method of `Stream.of`.

I can think of this workaround:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one");
Stream.of(list)
      .map(x -> x.toArray(new String[1]));
```

Or you can call the var-args method a bit differently:

```
 Stream.of(tropicalFruits, null)
       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
       .forEach(x -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x)));
```

Answer (score 5):

By calling `Stream#of` with a single `T[]`, Java defaults to the [vararg factory method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-), creating a `Stream<T>` rather than a `Stream<T[]>`.  To create a `Stream<T[]>` with a single element, you can either create a `Stream<T[]>` with multiple elements and call `limit(1)`, or use a dummy array for the second element:

```
Stream<String[]> stream = Stream.of(tropicalFruits, fruits).limit(1);

Stream<String[]> stream = Stream.of(tropicalFruits, new String[] {});
```