# Can I create a list of array with Arrays.asList?

Tags: java, list

Say I want to create a List which contains Integer[] arrays. But

```
Integer[] foo = {1,2,3};
List<Integer[]> bar = Arrays.asList(foo);
```

The second line wouldn't compile, because `Arrays.asList(foo)` will return a List with three Integer elements(namely 1, 2, 3), not a List with a single Integer[] element.

Since the documentation states the parameter of asList method as varargs of type T, I don't understand why the compiler doesn't interpret the second line as single argument of type Integer[] given. How do I get a List of single Array element?

```
List<Integer[]> bar = new ArrayList<Integer[]>(Arrays.asList(foo));
```

This is what I actually wanted to do, but it also doesn't compile, for the same reason I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  `Arrays.asList` takes a projection of your current array and flattens the first dimension into a `List`.  Since you only have one dimension, all of those elements get collected into the list.

You *could* do it if you had an `Integer[][]`.

Note:  `asList` accepts a vararg of `T` (so `T...`), which is effectively `T[]`.  If you substitute that with `Integer[][]`, you get `Integer[]`, since one dimension of your `Integer[][]` will satisfy `T...`'s type requirement.

Comment: Oh...can i always pass an array as argument wherever parameter is vararg in other context? Are they essentially the same thing?

Comment: @user8931048:  Yes, a `vararg` is typed as an array.  Be careful though, since not all vararg consumers are as forgiving as this one is.

Comment: I guess I have to do more research on that then. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

A [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48625931/7294647) was just asked the other day, but I suppose this is different enough for it not to be a duplicate.  You need to explicitly specify the generic type for it to compile, like so:

```
Integer[] foo = {1, 2, 3};        

List<Integer[]> list = Arrays.<Integer[]>asList(foo);
```

Comment: That question talks about streams.  This question makes absolutely no *mention* of streams.  In no universe would those two questions be duplicates.

Comment: @Makoto I mentioned above that it isn't a duplicate, but the solutions are essentially identical.

Comment: @Makoto This problem can be generalized as: *How to make the factory methods that accept a varargs argument take the array as one explicit argument instead of a varargs one?* So the reference to the linked question is valid, as the problem is exactly the same. The same happens with `List.of` in java 9, that's why it's [explicitly documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-).

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner:  There are still people out there using Java 7.

Comment: @Makoto I know, so it's not a duplicate. All I'm saying is that this is a general problem about varargs

Comment: @JacobG. I would mention that this approach is more efficient because it doesn't require to create a 2-dimension array to create a list of a 1-dimension array.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner If there is any performance difference, it would be very tiny (i.e. a *micro-optimisation*).

Comment: @Dukeling Sure, but why creating a new object if it's not needed? Why making the code less clear and less transparent w.r.t. the original intention of the developer? Why creating a 2d array if I need a 1d array?
 Why being less expressive? Hinting the compiler through the generic type of the method seems the best solution IMO.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I didn't say it's a worse solution, just that efficiency (performance) shouldn't really factor into this.

Comment: @Dukeling Maybe I sounded too harsh, sorry. You're right, performance shouldn't be taken into account for this. I totally agree.

Comment: I agree with both of you.  Performance is an important factor, but micro-optimization is as well.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner JacobG. Thanks for the links! Helped somewhat clarify things for me.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you actually need the ability to set the element to a different array, you can use:

```
List<Integer[]> list = Collections.singletonList(foo);
```

This is more efficient, because it is specialized to just holding one element: no array has to be created, contains is simply checking equality, size is always 1 etc.

Comment: Thanks! i just needed a copy of the array, so this would work alright.

Answer (score 2):

Varargs in java is just a syntactic sugar in Java. So, there is no difference between.

`Arrays.asList(1,2,3)` and `Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3})`.

So what you can do like below to solve your problem.

```
    Integer[][] foo = {{1,2,3}};
    List<Integer[]> bar = Arrays.asList(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList()` generates list of contents of array passed as argument. If you need to create list of arrays, you need to pass to this method **array of arrays** (e.g. `Integer[][]`).

When you pass to method `Integer[]` as argument instead of `Integer[][]` , it makes a list of contents of that array (in that case these are `Integer`s not arrays of `Integer`s).

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping your array in another array will achieve what you want:

```
Integer[] foo = {1,2,3};
List<Integer[]> bar = Arrays.asList(new Integer[][]{foo});
// OR
Integer[][] foo = {{1,2,3}};
List<Integer[]> bar = Arrays.asList(foo);
```

You could also just manually set the first element: (I'd probably say this is more readable, but opinions may vary)

```
Integer[] foo = {1,2,3};
List<Integer[]> bar = new ArrayList<>();
bar.set(0, foo);
```